# selenium Unable to locate element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to scrape web site to csv file, and there is some text elements that i just can't locate.

i keep getting
`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

i'm trying to get the elements with xpath, and i waiting to the site to load before i start to look for them.

my line of code that working for other elements in the [site](https://wolt.com/en/isr/rishon-lezion/restaurant/pizza-prego-rishon-lezion) (like the H1 title) is:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'descriptionContainer')]/p[1]").text`

and i tried couple of xpath to make sure:

```
//*[contains(@class,'VenueHeroBanner__description')]/p
//*div[contains(@class,'VenueHeroBanner__description')]/p
//*[contains(@class,'descriptionContainer')]/p[1]
//*[@id='venueHeroBanner']/div[2]/div[1]/p
```

** and all of them working in the chrome extension called:"xpath helper", but not in my script

note that i opening the the link in a new tab and then trying to get the element if its matters

```
driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{rest_links[0]}","_blank");''')
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i just need the entire page in csv sheet

Comment: You are seeing [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) how would you get the entire page in csv sheet? Please [edit the question](/posts/62619554/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I hope it's more clearer now for you

Answer (score 0):

The website seems to need some time to load the data.

[image: Pizzas]

You should add expecting conditions to your script.

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Then use :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "your_XPath"))).text
...
```

Side note : you should fix your last XPath (2 elements are returned).

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@class,'venueInfoLink')])[1]"))).get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: thanks but that's not it, i'm waiting 10 seconds in the code and for now i actually see the page loading . for example if you will enter this link: [link](https://wolt.com/en/isr/rishon-lezion/restaurant/pizza-prego-rishon-lezion) under the H1 (restaurant name ) there is the category name and i can get to the restaurant name any time but i can't  to get the category name by any means . its driving me crazy, i tried bunch of xpath and it just not getting it  ```//*[contains(@class,'VenueHeroBanner__description')]/p```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt understand way, but the xpath work if you give him the parent xpath of the child that you want to get

```html
<div class="VenueHeroBanner__descriptionContainer___3Q-jT">
    <p class="VenueHeroBanner__description___1wQwD xh-highlight">Bar & Restaurant</p>
```

not working-

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'descriptionContainer')]/p[1]").text
```

that one work:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'descriptionContainer')]").text
```

```
[output] "Bar & Restaurant"
```

Comment: Great ! Good job. Maybe the child of the `div` is not evaluated as a `p` element. What happens if you use  : `//*[contains(@class,'descriptionContainer')]/*[1]` Increase the position index (1) if necessary.